# How do I authenticate a Database User by a LDAP Server and then to login with the SQL Developer, without using the OID/Apex?

Tags: authentication, users, oracle-12c, oracle-apex, ldap

I want to create a global User, identified by a LDAP_DN.

My Problem is: I can automatically create users, but when I try to log on to the database, I get the error message that the login data are wrong.

> "CREATE USER 'TEST_ID' IDENTIFIED GLOBALLY AS 'LDAP_DN' DEFAULT
>   TABLESPACE Testuser TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP QUOTA 15M ON Testuser';"
>   it is my Term to create the User on the DB.

Admin_ACL&Assign_ACL files are created and the User got the "Connect" and the "Create Session" permissions.

I used the DBMS_LDAP Package to connect to the LDAP Server("init") and then i tried to "bind" with an Account. That was successful.

I 've googled a lot, but i cant find a way to authenticate my Database_User without using an OID / Apex.

I'm using an Oracle 12c Database on a virtual machine  and the LDAP Server is a OpenDJ http://opendj.forgerock.org/ ,LDAP V3.
[image: Database Version]

I dont understand why I can use DBMS_LDAP Package without any Problems, but the `IDENTIFIED GLOBALLY` Term  doesnt work. I already tried to activate the Oci/Thick Driver on the Sql Deveolper, but i only got problems.

Do you have any idea how I can solve the Problem without using the OID?

Maybe someone can explain how the *"Identified Globally"* Term and the password encryption from Orace 12c works exactly?